# makeKeyAndVisible for secondary screen stops UIMenuController from appearing

Tags: iphone, ipad, uimenucontroller

I present a UIMenuController over a view to display a copy and paste menu popup. This works great, but recently I added external screen functionality to my app. When I present a view and add it to the external screen I call

...

```
 [extWindow setScreen:extScreen];
 [extWindow addSubview:viewController.view];
 [extWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

...

but the `[extWindow makeKeyAndVisible];` appears to have the side effect of stopping my menu appearing in the view that is still on the iPad.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIMenuController does indeed display to the current key window - I'd not set it back to the main window. Moral of the story is to make sure the window you want the menu to appear in is key.